# Why do negative binomial regression coefficients differ by level of data stratification and coefficients from Poisson models do not?

Tags: r, regression, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I'm trying to understand why regression coefficients from negative binomial models are sensitive to the level of stratification of the data and regression coefficients from Poisson models are not.  The motivation for this question is to understand what level of stratification is appropriate when multiple levels of stratification are available.

Here's a example of the issue:

First, stratify the data in two different ways

```r
# example adapted from 
# http://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/heather_turner/glmCourse_003.pdf

library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
data(ships)

ships.fullstrat <- ships %>%
  filter(service > 0) %>%
  mutate(year = as.factor(year))

ships.partstrat <- ships.fullstrat %>%
  group_by(year, period) %>%
  summarise(incidents = sum(incidents), service = sum(service))


ships.partstrat
ships.fullstrat
```

Then run Poisson and negative binomial models for both levels of data stratification.

```r
poi.fullstrat <- glm(formula = incidents ~ year, family = poisson, data = ships.fullstrat, offset = log(service))
poi.partstrat <- glm(formula = incidents ~ year, family = poisson, data = ships.partstrat, offset = log(service))


nb.fullstrat <- glm.nb(formula = incidents ~ year + offset(log(service)), data = ships.fullstrat)
nb.partstrat <- glm.nb(formula = incidents ~ year + offset(log(service)), data = ships.partstrat)


coef(poi.fullstrat)
coef(poi.partstrat)
coef(nb.fullstrat)
coef(nb.partstrat)
```

Coefficients from the Poisson models are the same whereas coefficients from the negative binomial models are different:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  model.strat  |    term     | estimate | std.error |
+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| poi.fullstrat | (Intercept) |    -6.82 |      0.12 |
| poi.fullstrat | year65      |     0.81 |      0.15 |
| poi.fullstrat | year70      |      1.2 |      0.15 |
| poi.fullstrat | year75      |     0.97 |      0.21 |
| poi.partstrat | (Intercept) |    -6.82 |      0.12 |
| poi.partstrat | year65      |     0.81 |      0.15 |
| poi.partstrat | year70      |      1.2 |      0.15 |
| poi.partstrat | year75      |     0.97 |      0.21 |
| nb.fullstrat  | (Intercept) |    -6.75 |      0.29 |
| nb.fullstrat  | year65      |     1.04 |      0.35 |
| nb.fullstrat  | year70      |     1.31 |      0.34 |
| nb.fullstrat  | year75      |     0.93 |       0.4 |
| nb.partstrat  | (Intercept) |    -6.77 |      0.15 |
| nb.partstrat  | year65      |     0.77 |      0.19 |
| nb.partstrat  | year70      |     1.13 |       0.2 |
| nb.partstrat  | year75      |     0.92 |      0.26 |
+---------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

I would add that dispersion statistics are different for these four models:

```r
#disp function from Hilbe, Modeling Count Data

disp <- function(x) {
  pr <- sum(residuals(x, type="pearson")^2)
  dispersion <- pr/x$df.residual
  cat("\n Pearson Chi2 = ", pr ,
      "\n Dispersion = ", dispersion, "\n")
}

disp(poi.fullstrat)
disp(poi.partstrat)
disp(nb.fullstrat)
disp(nb.partstrat)

# disp(poi.fullstrat)
# Pearson Chi2 =  95.89112 
# Dispersion =  3.196371 
# 
# disp(poi.partstrat)
# Pearson Chi2 =  13.17882 
# Dispersion =  4.392939 
# 
# disp(nb.fullstrat)
# Pearson Chi2 =  40.53241 
# Dispersion =  1.35108 
# 
# disp(nb.partstrat)
# Pearson Chi2 =  8.038155 
# Dispersion =  2.679385
```

Comment: Because the sum of Poisson deviates is again Poisson (with a different mean), but the sum of NB deviates is not NB with the same dispersion parameter and a different mean ... ?